# How do I remove Newline and or Carrige return characters in an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that I need to convert into a csv file for import into a database.  The Excel sheet has one column of cells that some have return characters, I think because I can't see what it really is there, causing my csv file to have extra records that should be apart of the previous recordset.  I tried Vba code around it but only got some of the return characters, code below.

```
Public Sub GetCarriageReturn()

Dim mString As String


    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        mString = Cells(i, "B")
        LfPosition = InStr(mString, vbLf) 'Chr(10)
        'MsgBox LfPosition
        If LfPosition > 0 Then
            mNewString = Left(mString, LfPosition - 2) & " " & Mid(mString, LfPosition + 1, 20)
            Trim (mNewString)
            'Debug.Print mNewString
            Cells(i, "B").Value = mNewString
        End If

        CrPosition = InStr(mString, vbCr) 'Chr(10)
        'MsgBox CrPosition
        If CrPosition > 0 Then
            mNewString = Left(mString, CrPosition - 2) & " " & Mid(mString, CrPosition + 1, 20)
            Trim (mNewString)
            'Debug.Print mNewString
            Cells(i, "B").Value = mNewString
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

What am I missing here?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub TryThis()
    Cells.Replace what:=vbCr, Replacement:=" "
    Cells.Replace what:=vbLf, Replacement:=" "
End Sub
```

It should scan all the cells in the worksheet and replace both *ASCII10* and *ASCII13* with blanks.